# Block of 64 public IP's, how many usable?

Tags: nat

We have been assigned a block of 64 IP's by ARIN (/26).  We have a private range that is a /22.  Every time we get a new block of public IP's we NAT them to the next available addresses in that range, so no new private subnets being made for this new /26 block.

My question is: how many will be usable by hosts?  Normally I'd say 61 (1 for network, 1 for gateway, 1 for broadcast) but with a public block not sure.

Comment: to have someone properly answer this question you must include details about the amount of users/services/etc. Also, this is probably a better question for chat since it is opinion-oriented. If you are able to provide services and approx # of hosts I will gladly answer with the math that i would recommend

Comment: Those details aren't necessary at all.  It's simple: 64 public IP's from ARIN, how many are usable/NATable and why?

Comment: This is still worded as an opinion-based question, please revise it. Your question is akin to "i have a /24, what ip do i give my router and how many do i assign to hosts?" If your question is simply asking how many of the 64 addresses do you have the CAPABILITY to nat, that is a different question than what you have asked.

Comment: Edited for clarity, I was asking about capability.  I included a bit more context as well.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: This still really hinges on the equipment in use and how the network is designed.  This could be all of them, or it could be 61, 59, etc.

Comment: So.. I need to know how equipment factors into how many IP addresses are usable in a public block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IP addresses are IP addresses are IP addresses.  Until (and unless!) you end up with an assignment of IP addresses in an ethernet (or ethernet-like) network, there is no concept of "network address" "broadcast address" and the like.

NAT functions are not "an ethernet(-like) network", so all IP addresses in a block like that are usable in a NAT configuration.

There's a very strong argument to be made for not setting NAT configurations up like that, though.  If you're just mapping one set of IP addresses up as 1-1 NAT mappings to another "private" (air-quotes intended) set of IP addresses, then why not just assign the public addresses directly onto the systems and eliminate the NAT altogether?

Comment: Hey Jeff, thanks for a clear answer.  As far as why they're not assigned directly to the boxes I couldn't say as I'm not directly involved with those decisions, I just saw the ticket on our end and the discussion along the same line and it made me wonder :)